# count array begins with specific characters

Tags: php, arrays

For example,

```
echo count($_GET);
```

prints number of all the values, how to count values begins with "cat".

Value is like

```
array(2) {
  ["cat1"]=>
  string(1) "a"
  ["cat2"]=>
  string(1) "b"
  ["dog1"]=>
  string(1) "c"
}
```

Comment: 1. Iterate it with foreach 2. Check with `strpos` if it begins with "cat" 3. Increment a counter.

Answer (score 2):

Use preg grep

```
$list = array ( 'cat1', 'cat2', 'dog' );
$res = preg_grep ('/^cat/i', $list);
print_r(count($res));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$list = array ( 'cat1', 'cat2', 'dog' );
$numCat = 0;
array_walk($list, function($v) use(&$numCat) {substr($v, 0, 3) == 'cat' ? $numCat += 1 :  '';});
echo $numCat;
```

Answer (score 0):

Get all the keys of array $_GET with [array_keys](https://secure.php.net/manual/es/function.array-keys.php) method, match the ones needed with [preg_rep](https://secure.php.net/manual/es/function.preg-grep.php) checking for strings that start with the desired string, and count the number of them matched.

```
count(preg_rep('/^cat/',array_keys($_GET)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check with a loop, get the first three characters of the string key value using `substr` and then compare that to the word "cat" using `strcmp`:

```
$cats = 0;
foreach ($_GET as $key => $val){
     if(strcmp(substr($key,0,3),'cat')==0){
          $cats++;
     }
}
echo $cats;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is other way,

```
echo count(array_filter($_GET, function($key) {
                      return strpos($key, 'cat') === 0;
},ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY));
```

I hope this will help.